# Python matplotlib animation is lagging when I continue drwign lines

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a long line starting at one point and then, after certain time, it creates new point, which would be the next point of the line. So it should look like a path. But I have got a problem, when the line gets longer, computer has got problem to compute it and it starts lagging. I think, that the program should run at the same speed during the time, except if it uses exponentialy more space on the disk or drawing same points again. I don't know, what causes these difficulties, can you please suggest some way, how to improve it?

Here is example of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import matplotlib.animation as animation

CELLS: list = []
# number of cells
NUM_CELLS: int = 100

# how big is the move
MAX_STEP: int = 10

# how many ms does it take to update → higher means slower
SPEED: int = 10


fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(0, 1000)
plt.axis("off")

def create_cell():
    y_coord = random.randint(0, 1000)
    x_coord = random.randint(0, 1000)
    CELLS.append([x_coord, y_coord])
    
def move(self):
    new_cells = []
    for cell in CELLS:
        x_coord1 = cell[0]
        y_coord1 = cell[1]
        
        move_x = random.randint(-1, 1)
        
        move_y = random.randint(-1, 1)

        x_coord2 = cell[0] + (MAX_STEP * move_x)
        y_coord2 = cell[1] + (MAX_STEP * move_y)
        x_coords = [x_coord1, x_coord2]
        y_coords = [y_coord1, y_coord2]
        
        plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords, color="blue")

        new_cells.append([x_coord2, y_coord2])
    
    CELLS.clear()
    for point in new_cells:
        CELLS.append(point)

for i in range(NUM_CELLS):
    create_cell()

animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, move, frames=100, interval = SPEED)

plt.show()
```

Comment: A simple example in the docs does exactly what you want: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Comment: Thank you for it. It helped me, it is what I was looking for. Now, it is working

Answer (score 1):

If you use `plot` only once and then update the data using `set_data`, it will go much quicker.

I have changed 3 lines in your snippet, seems to run pretty quickly now.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import matplotlib.animation as animation

CELLS: list = []
# number of cells
NUM_CELLS: int = 100

# how big is the move
MAX_STEP: int = 10

# how many ms does it take to update → higher means slower
SPEED: int = 10


fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(0, 1000)
plt.axis("off")

line, = plt.plot([], [], color="blue") #changed

def create_cell():
    
    y_coord = random.randint(0, 1000)
    x_coord = random.randint(0, 1000)
    CELLS.append([x_coord, y_coord])

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def move(self):
    new_cells = []
    for cell in CELLS:
        x_coord1 = cell[0]
        y_coord1 = cell[1]
        
        move_x = random.randint(-1, 1)
        
        move_y = random.randint(-1, 1)

        x_coord2 = cell[0] + (MAX_STEP * move_x)
        y_coord2 = cell[1] + (MAX_STEP * move_y)
        x_coords = [x_coord1, x_coord2]
        y_coords = [y_coord1, y_coord2]

        new_cells.append([x_coord2, y_coord2])
    
    CELLS.clear()
    for point in new_cells:
        CELLS.append(point)
    line.set_data([point[0] for point in new_cells], [point[1] for point in new_cells]) #changed
    return line, #changed

for i in range(NUM_CELLS):
    create_cell()

animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, move, init_func=init, frames=100, interval = SPEED) #changed

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it displays many lines in different directions, and these lines are just shaking. Any of these lines are creating in a real time.